# Google Drive integration and listening to push notifications for permissions change on all containing folders

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to listen to permissions changes on documents belonging to my app in a user's Drive, and I'm looking at push notifications on the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push).

Suppose I'm watching all files that belong to my application (using `POST`s of the form `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/watch`), and the user moves a few such files into a folder inside another folder inside another folder, and then shares the top-level folder with another user. Will I receive push notifications for every file in that folder, or will I have had to subscribe to changes on that folder separately?

If the latter, how do I know that I'm supposed to subscribe to that folder (i.e. how do I get notified that it exists/what its ID is)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-drive-api-push-notifications.html), a better way to keep you notified is to let your app subscribe for changes to a user’s drive and get notified whenever changes occur.

Subscription can be done as shown in the blog with sample domain:

```
String subscriptionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  Channel request = new Channel()
    .setId(subscriptionId)
    .setType("web_hook")
    .setAddress("https://my-host.com/notification");
  drive.changes().watch(request).execute();
```

With active subscription, Google Drive will trigger a web-hook callback at `https://my-host.com/notification`.

You might want to refer more on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) or try going through this [GitHub](https://github.com/googledrive/pushnotifications-playground) for more information and implementation codes.

Hope that helps!